# Unable to load configuration file from instance folder when deploying app

Tags: python, flask

I set up a new virtualenv for my app, to clean up the installed packages.  I have a `config.py` file in the app's instance folder.  There are two configs, one for dev in the 'instance' folder and one for production in the root folder.  The app worked in the old env, but now I get an error that it couldn't find the config file.  Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 12, in <module>
    application.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
  File "/Users/pavsidhu/Envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/config.py", line 128, in from_pyfile
    with open(filename) as config_file:
IOError: [Errno 2] Unable to load configuration file (No such file or directory): '/Users/pavsidhu/Envs/test/var/application-instance/config.py'
```

My project structure looks like:

```
/Users/pavsidhu/Envs/test/
    lib/python-3.4/site-packages/
    bin/
    application.py
    static/
    templates/
    instance/
        config.py
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flask thinks your app is installed in the env because you put it in the same base directory as the env.  This behavior is described in detail [in the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#instance-folders).

> Installed module or package:
>
> ```
> $PREFIX/lib/python2.X/site-packages/myapp
> $PREFIX/var/myapp-instance
> ```
>
> $PREFIX is the prefix of your Python installation.

Flask expects the instance folder to be at `var/myapp-instance` when installed this way.  (The structure isn't exactly the same, but it's similar enough to fool Flask's [detection function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.auto_find_instance_path).)

You should not mix your project structure with the virtualenv structure.  Separate the two:

```
my_env/
    lib/
    bin/
my_project/
    my_app/
        __init__.py
        static/
        templates/
    instance/
```

[See the comment discussion moved to chat for further details.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/82103/2015/7/1)

Answer (score 1):

The "best practice" is to embed/distribute your default configuration as a module inside of your application.  Then load configuration override values from a file based on an environment variable.  This is described [in the Flask Configuration Handling documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#configuration-best-practices).  I would follow the best practice instead of relying on directory names to separate them.  What I have done in the past is something like the following *app.py*:

```
import flask

class Application(flask.Flask):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Application, self).__init__(name)
        self.config.from_object('mypackage.config')
        self.config.from_envvar('APP_CONFIG', silent=True)

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('host', self.config['HOST'])
        kwargs.setdefault('port', self.config['PORT'])
        kwargs.setdefault('debug', self.config['DEBUG'])
        return super(Application, self).run(*args, **kwargs)


app = Application(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def root_handler():
    return 'Hi there'
```

The *config.py* module is simple:

```
import os

DEBUG = False
TESTING = False
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '8000'))
HOST = os.environ.get('HOST', '127.0.0.1')
SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(24)
```

I use environment variables for a number of configurable values by default since application hosting provides (e.g., heroku) and command line tools (e.g., [honcho](https://honcho.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) set them to useful values.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and fixed changing my Current Working Directory to be equal to the Projects Directory.

Debbuging, I figured out that for some reason, the `instance_path = os.getcwd() + /instance` when the Flask().import_name attribute is a string called `'__name__'`.