# Can't build Dockerfile -: Not a directory Error using ADD command

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to make a dockerfile for a python/flask webapp and keep running into issues inspite of multiple changes based off what I've read

The Dockerfile I have at present is as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

#Update OS
RUN sed -i 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# Install Python
RUN apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip

# Add requirements.txt
ADD requirements.txt /webapp
ADD requirements.txt .

# Install uwsgi Python web server
RUN pip install uwsgi

# Install app requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Create app directory
ADD . /webapp

# Set the default directory for our environment
ENV HOME /webapp
WORKDIR /webapp

# Expose port 8000 for uwsgi
EXPOSE 8000


ENTRYPOINT ["uwsgi", "--http", "127.0.0.1:8000", "--module", "app:app", "--processes", "1", "--threads", "8"]
#ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Attempting to run this Dockerfile with the command `sudo docker build -t imgcomparer .`

gives the error:

```
Step 10/15 : ADD . /webapp
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Error setting up pivot dir: mkdir /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/53420471c832e61b7f75ac5fc5268d64b932a4d589a8464c63bf5868f127ff04/webapp/.pivot_root981494252: not a directory
```

After some research, I discovered that putting a trailing `/` at the end of the path would work (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173452/docker-error-processing-tar-fileexit-status-1-error-setting-up-pivot-dir-no) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075418/dockerhub-automated-build-fails-not-a-directory-when-adding-file))

Upon doing that (and the same on the following lines) I have the following in my dockerfile:

```
# Create app directory
ADD . /webapp/

# Set the default directory for our environment
ENV HOME /webapp/
WORKDIR /webapp/
```

that gives this error:

```
Step 10/15 : ADD . /webapp/
stat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/f37b19a8d72d39cbbdfb0bae6359aee499fab0515e2415e251a50d528708bdd3/webapp/: not a directory
```

Last, I tried removing the problematic line altogether. When I have

```
# Create app directory
# ADD . /webapp

# Set the default directory for our environment
ENV HOME /webapp
WORKDIR /webapp
```

The docker file successfully builds! But, unsurprisingly, trying to run it gives an error:

`sudo docker run -t imgcomparer`

```
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/webapp\") set in config.json failed: not a directory"
: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.
```

Directory Structure is as follows

```
app.py
image_data.db
README.txt
requirements.txt
Dockerfile
templates
 - index.html
static/
 - image.js
 - main.css
 img/
   - camera.png
 images/
   - empty
```

Comment: Fiat you need to create the webapp directory, something like `RUN mkdir /webapp`

Comment: I put that immediately before the ADD command and it gives the error: `mkdir: cannot create directory '/webapp/': File exists`

Comment: I think the problem is that earlier you are using `ADD requirements.txt /webapp`, which is probably creating a file called `webapp`. Therefore, you can't then treat it as a directory

Comment: BTW, I don't think the `python` tag applies to this question

Comment: I added it to before the `ADD requirements.txt` line and now it builds... but it does not run!  I get an error that `imgcomparer unable to load configuration from app.py`

Comment: BTW, Are you the same jorge who made the "From Zero" Python Flask Docker tutorials? I've been watching them to try and figure this all out. haha.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to create the directory before referencing to it:

```
RUN mkdir /webapp
```

**edit:**

(before `ADD requirements.txt /webapp`)

With

```
ADD somefile.ext /folder
```

(without trailing slash to the folder) you reference a file, so you get a file named `folder` at the root directory, with the contents of `somefile.ext` in it.
Be careful when you need to reference a directory and when a file.

Thus you could also:

```
ADD requirements.txt /webapp/
```

Besides: why do you add `requirements.txt` twice? You should aim for a little steps as possible in a Dockerfile, so you could do:

```
[...]
RUN apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip && \
    pip install uwsgi
ADD . /webapp/
RUN pip install -r /webapp/requirements.txt
[...]
```

Comment: Hmmm... That gives `mkdir: cannot create directory '/webapp/': File exists
The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir /webapp/' returned a non-zero code: 1
`

I put it immediately before the ADD line that is giving me trouble.

Comment: Did you put it BEFORE `ADD requirements.txt /webapp`?

Comment: Ah! I had it before `ADD . /webapp` Moving it further back made it properly build.... but (of course) it does not run. I get an error that `imgcomparer
unable to load configuration from app.py
`

Comment: I think that has nothing to do with Docker. See for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164127/unable-to-load-configuration-file-from-instance-folder-when-deploying-app

Comment: In fact you had to `docker build --no-cache .` in order to not use the cache and moving that instruction further back invalidated the cache :-)